# WSO2 API Manager How to prevent subscriber freely subscribe to API but keep the API visible

Tags: api, wso2, authorize, api-manager, subscriber

WSO2 API Manager How to prevent subscriber freely subscribe to API but keep the API visible (how to add approval function before grant a subscription)

Could anyone assist on how to limit a subscriber to freely subscribe to an API?
For example I have APIs called "contracts" and "parties", they are visible by user who has role "subscriber" hence subscriber can subscribes the both APIs. I would like to limit this so only authorized subscriber can subscribe to the API.

I understand that you can filter the API accessible by role - this is not the answer

I understand that you can block the subscription from publisher - this is also not the answer

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, J Phiong. Welcome to stackoverflow, please read the entire [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before make a question. Not all questions work well in stackoverflow format. Avoid unnecessaries comments like "thank you".

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved using a workflow with WSO2 API Manager. When subscription workflow is enabled, whoever subscribes will be put on hold until the subscription is approved.

Please refer this [document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+an+API+Subscription+Workflow) for more information.